# How to utilize if/else condition for JSON column formatting in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting, column-formatting, if-condition

I am trying to format the color of a column based on the selection of another column in the same View. But, I am having trouble writing the JSON to check for multiple values in the other column. Here is my code so far that only checks for one selection, "Red". I want it to check for the other possible options, which are "Green", "Blue", "Amber", and "Gray".

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$OtherColumn] == 'Red', 'red', '')"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it similar to that in Excel :)

You can checkout the below sample to get an idea:

```
"background-color": "= if([$OtherColumn] == 'Red', 'red', 
if([$OtherColumn] == 'Green', 'green', 
if([$OtherColumn] == 'Amber', 'amber', 
if([$OtherColumn] == 'Gray', 'gray', 'blue'))))"
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's giving me the "Please enter valid column-formatting JSON." error.

Comment: I got it to work! It all had to be in one line (no line breaks for each "if"). Thanks!

Comment: ahh, i used them for better reading experience, but used the actual no-line breaks in real code, facepalm :( . Happy to help. You can also [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by ticking the checkmark besides the answer, cheers :) !!

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, Unfortunately it does not seem to work. Maybe I should have precised that I'm using SP online? An imge that coould help: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Nva.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Nva.png)